# Can a person be 'in perpetual motion'?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I feel like I have seen fidgety people described as being in perpetual motion before, however when I googled it to see if this was the correct usage of the term all I could find where perpetual motion machines. I was fairly certain this was an actual phrase you could describe people with, but could not find any evidence to suggest it was. Does anyone know if you can use the phrase like that? If so where have you seen it used?

I'm aware of the what the words mean seperately, I'm asking as they seem to have a different connotation/meaning when used together as a phrase

Comment: It's a transferred usage, and would not be used of a person in the most formal of registers.

Comment: Look in a dictionary for "perpetual" and for "motion".  Congratulations, you now know as much as anyone else is to whether a person can be "in perpetual motion".

Comment: a ceaselessly moving individual

Comment: Understand that "perpetual motion", in this sense, is hyperbole.

Comment: In referring to a fidgety person as being in perpetual motion, a skillful writer would be deliberately making a playful allusion to the primary use of that phrase for the (hypothetical) perpetual-motion machines, and expect the audience to recognise that. One shouldn't use the phrase that way if one doesn't have this intention.

Comment: Technically, the answer to the question "can a machine be in perpetual motion?" is no. So you do the math.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase itself is slang as it is not meant to be used with the actual meanings of the word perpetual.

If a person is described as being in perpetual motion, they are describing the person as always moving or in constant motion, which is what a fidgety person would appear to be doing.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to call it "slang". It's closer to "casual". It wouldn't surprise me to see a character in a book being described as being "in perpetual motion".

Answer (score 0):

Perpetual motion, when dealing with human kind, can also relate to the psychological movement of that human, rendering very little rest and extraordinary movement both physically and mentally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).